# Create .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemset

Is there a way to create the associated `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files when creating a new gemset?

With older versions of rvm, one could do `rvm --create --rvmrc 1.8.7@project`, but that creates `.rvmrc` files.

I thought I read somewhere we could use the `--ruby-version` command line switch, but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.

Answer (score 96):

I recently had the same problem. `rvm --help` led me to:

```
rvm --create --ruby-version ruby-1.9.3@my-gemset
```

It created both *.ruby-gemset* and *.ruby-version*.

Comment: And what if you already created the gemset? Will you be forced to add .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset manually at that point?

Comment: @Donato no, this will simply create the files, and move aside any existing .ruby-version or .ruby-gemset file into .ruby-gemset.Todays.Date.Time. In your project, type `ls -a` to verify the hidden files are there and as you expect.

Comment: `rvm --create --ruby-version use ruby-x.x.x@project`

Answer (score 41):

According to [the official RVM docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects) you can use this:

```
echo 1.9.3 > .ruby-version
```

Or you can use this:

```
rvm --ruby-version use 1.9.3@my_app
```

The second form will create both `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`.

Comment: if you want to only specify a ruby version and do it with `rvm` you would do: `rvm --ruby-version use 1.9.3`. This only creates a `.ruby-version` file.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose I am creating gemset for my rails app whose name is **tptapp** then we can do it in following way.

```
rvm use 2.2.2@tptapp --create
```

here **tptapp** is name of gemset, 2.2.2 is Ruby version.

Answer (score 3):

All of the above examples require you to type in your ruby version and gemset name .. which is close to the same keystrokes required to vi .ruby-gemset and vi .ruby-version. Assuming you are in a directory where you've already chosen your ruby version and you are pointing at the desired gemset.. this does the trick.

```
rvm --ruby-version use $(rvm-prompt)
```