# Rails Seeing Incorrect Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've built a Rails 5 app and it's working great but I'd like to change the Ruby version I'm running it on. I'm using RVM 1.27.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I copied the app folder to a different path and changed the versions on .ruby_version and my Gemfile:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.2"
```

.ruby_version:

```
ruby-2.2.2
```

Once I updated these I moved out and back into the folder and ran a ruby -v:

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
```

I then ran a bundle install and everything installed without error.

However, when I ran rake -T I get this:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2.
```

My $PATH looks good:

```
/home/ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/home/ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/home/ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/home/ken/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

What am I missing? Where is Rails pulling the Ruby version from? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a system bundler which is why you're seeing a different version of ruby. All you need to do is install bundler under your current ruby version:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Once you do a bundle install you'll get the gem's built for the correct ruby version.

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

The file name should be `.ruby-version`, not `.ruby_version`.

And you also should have file .ruby-gemset with content

```
gemset
```

check this link, [Create .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset with rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142065/create-ruby-version-and-ruby-gemset-with-rvm)

You can also try `spring stop` and `gem install bundler`

Comment: This didn't work. Still getting the same error and now bundler isn't even installing. :(

Comment: @user3063045 can u provide the host name && password to me? my email is dilin.life@gmail.com.  I have keep using rvm for long time.

Comment: Thank you for the offer but no. I don't even use passwords on my host.

Comment: @user3063045 try`spring stop`, it might be a cache problem